# Discord.py rock paper scissors with a player - problem with waiting on a message

Tags: python, pycharm, discord.py

I have been trying to create a rock, paper, scissors game in my discord.py for about 3 hours but i have no idea how to to wait on a message of the second player if he wants to play or not and then how to wait on  message of both players and finally let the bot react based on if they had picked rock, paper or scissors.

Here is what i have for now, I have tried many things but now I'm out of ideas. At first the bot checks if the message is in right channel and if the author of the message isn't the bot itself. Then if the message starts with !rps the bot stores the message as a message and the bot checks if the fifth position isn't empty.

Then the bot stores id from a user I want to play with (simply with fifth to last position) to be able to mention him in the next message, which bot sends him to ask him if he wants to play or not (there is that > in the message, that is because `[5:-1]` doesn't store the last position but the last position is > so it doesn't matter and i just add it to the message).

And then I have no idea how to continue, I don't know how to check if the next message is from the user I want to play with and how to check if he said yes or no and if he says yes I have no idea how to wait for another 2 messages from both users. Also I thought that would be better to use a command for this but i have no idea how to store `msg.content` in command and also how to store id from a user I want to play with.

[image: Here is how it looks like in discord for now:]

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
bot_id = 791774902986080316
channel = 797224597443051611

@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    chat = bot.get_channel(797224597443051611)
    if msg.author.id == bot_id:
        return
    if msg.channel.id != channel:
        return
    if msg.content.startswith("!rps"):
        message = msg.content
        if message[5] == " ":
            return
        id = (message[5:-1])
        print(id)
        await chat.send(id + "> Do you want to play ?\n(y) yes\n(n) no")
        await bot.wait_for("message", check=lambda msg: msg.content == "y" or "n")
        if msg.content == "y":
            await chat.send(msg.author.mention + " " + id + "> The game begins, write: <rock> <paper> <scissors>")
            ...
        if msg.content == "n":
            await chat.send(msg.author.mention + "im sorry, the player doesnt want to play")
    await bot.process_commands(msg)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing a couple things here. `msg` is the original message that called `!rps`, whereas you want to work with the **next** message that is sent. You can get this message using the `wait_for` that you are already doing.

```
their_msg = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
```

then define check this way

```
def check(message):
  return message.content in ['y', 'n']
```

or with a lambda:

```
check = lambda message: message.content in ['y', 'n']
```

now `their_msg` won't return until it meets this criteria. You don't need to check the content yourself afterwards.

If you want to respond when the user declines the game, I would wait for *any* message instead, rather than one starts with `y` or `n`.

```
check = lambda message: True
```

This way the check will pass for *any* message, and you can process `their_msg.content` to see what it is.

Comment: Also, as an aside, you should consider moving this to a command, so you don't need to check if the content is `!rps` ... Discord.py is designed to avoid writing that code over and over.

Comment: Seems to work, thank you so much. I will also add an option to play only with bot but i hope that i will manage by myself.